# Can I plant lucky bamboo in an aquarium with fish?

Tags: fish, aquarium

I am planting a 10 gallon fish tank project with fish. I was considering planting lucky bamboo in a jar in a biube tank. I researched that lucky bamboo in a jar needs low or moderate light for good growth. My fish tank is led's will be on at night only. Will the lighting in the tank affect the lucky bamboo plant?

Comment: I can't tell if biube tank is a type of tank or a typo?

Comment: *"My fish tank is led's will be on at night only."* This sounds like "you're doing it wrong". Don't use the light to fight the normal day/night cycle, your fishes need it.

Comment: The plants I see are some dracenea , They can survive , but more of a bog palnt.

Answer (score 6):

While you *can* grow lucky bamboo in a tank, it's not advisable. While bamboo roots need to be submerged in water, submerging the leaves and stalk will cause the plant to die in time. One way to get bamboo for your tank is to plant it in the filter. This way the roots will always stay submerged, but the rest of the plant won't rot.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. They can be completely submerged. They grow slower, though. Get a substrate created for planted aquariums. Remember get now I have 8 stalks and have had them completely submerged 4 for a year, 3 for 2 years, and 1 for 3 years. I haven’t had one die.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I followed your answer and planted some bamboo into my tank. They've grown so well, and they look really pretty. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are several reports of people growing lucky bamboo completely underwater in a fish tank. I would personally not try it since it could die and foul the water, but if you let the leaves out of the water the stalk should do fine in the water.

Else the suggestion of Wes Austin of planting it in the filter is a good one. I also saw people hanging it half in the tank and the other half out of it. This will leave the root exposed witch bring more hiding place and another look. This last option seems more safe for both, the plant and fish.

[image: Tank with 2 underwater bamboo plants fed with liquid plant food]